# Redirect to inferior

Tags: templating

So how do i redirect to error/inferior template.  I could add my template at the templates folder but thats not really nice.  Is there something like `{% exit 404 %}` but for the inferior page?

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing if this a channel, structure or single and no provided code I can't give you a detailed answer, but I think you are looking for Craft's redirect tag.

[Redirect Tag](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/redirect)

Comment: I want to redirect to inferior when the browser is unsupported, so i will redirect like a simple template there is no other way something like exit for the 404, right?

Comment: What you mean by "browser is unsupported"?

Comment: I mean that i have a list of browser versions that my project supports and if the users browser is not one of them i will redirect him to the error/inferior template.So i just want to know if there is something specific for doing that or i'll have to do it with a redirect tag.

Comment: Craft out of the box can determine if the browser is mobile or not, but I don't think it can determine the browser/version without a plugin. I might be wrong here, any other peeps here can comment. Once determined, you can use Craft's redirect tag in the link above.

Comment: Sounds like the OP already has a solution in place for figuring out if a certain browser is "supported" or not. If not, yes, there's the [`isMobileBrowser()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.request#isMobileBrowser) method. There's also the [`Detect`](https://github.com/mmikkel/Detect-Craft) plugin, if you need to get specific :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you mean by an "inferior template" but I assume you're talking about either a scaled down version of your site or just a custom error template. Tons of ways to skin this cat, here are some options:

You can name your error/inferior template after [a semi-appropriate HTTP status](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14511133/4663184), and exit using that status (the below will load `/templates/403.html`, if it exists):

```
{% if browserNotSupported %}
    {% redirect 403 %}
{% endif %}
```

You can redirect to a different URI:

```
{% if browserNotSupported %}
    {% redirect '/some/other/url' %}
{% endif %}
```

You can also include a different template, e.g.

```
{% if browserNotSupported %}
    {% include '_inferior' %}
{% else %}
    {# Your other template or code #}
{% endif %}
```

...or you can use a ternary operation to [extend](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html) a different layout:

```
{% extends browserNotSupported ? '_inferior' : '_layout' %}
{# Template code #}
```